# Django flatpages and images

Tags: django, django-flatpages

I'm interested in using the Flatpages app for my project but would also like a place (somewhere in the admin) to upload images that I want to reference on those flatpages.

Is there a way to do this without resorting to a CMS app?

Comment: Better approach is to consider extending the FlatPages model: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021487/add-functionality-to-django-flatpages-without-changing-the-original-django-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplest way is to upload images to a photo hosting (picasa, flickr etc). If you prefer to stick with django admin, you can write a simple app with a single model like this:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    title    = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    file    = ImageField(upload_to='car_images')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return (self.file and self.file.url) or ''
```